# Give a vector pair i have to find no. of pairs such that a number k is greater than first and smaller than second

Tags: algorithm, sorting, vector, time-complexity, binary-search

**number of i such that v[i].first<=k<=v[i].second in log(n) complexity**

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Absolutely not possible to do this in less than O(n) time, unless you know something about the array that you haven't told us.

Answer (score 0):

A hint big enough to be considered an answer: given `x` array elements less than or equal to `k`, for each array element, `e`, greater than or equal to `k` (excluding `e`), there are `x` such pairs.